# how to send data from sensor to cloud service in background using process in python?

Tags: python, multithreading, amazon-web-services, raspberry-pi, iot

i have two sensors which is used to detect objects and when objects passes it gives output of no of boxes passed in the conveyor. i'm doing a iot application in aws and this code is running in raspberry pi3 using python. i want to take continuous output from multiple sensor and also send the sensor values to cloud url simultaneously. is there any one can help me how to do multiprocessing with this input...

```
from  multiprocessing import Process
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import urllib2
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(4, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)
GPIO.setup(17, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)
global t,t1
t=0
t1=0
def photo():
    global t
    while 1:
           i= GPIO.input(4)
           if i == 1:
              time.sleep(.1)
              j= GPIO.input(4)
              if j == 0:
                 t=t+1
                 print "photo sensor output",t, time.ctime(time.time())
                 connection =    urllib2.urlopen("https://5fhwrhjoc3.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/production/productioncount?skey=76b89337-206c-4de3-a553- 177dbf74e4ea&device_id=1&count="+str(t))
def proxi():
    global t1 
    while 1:
          a= GPIO.input(17)
          if a == 1:
             time.sleep(.1)
             b= GPIO.input(17)
          if b == 0:
             t1=t1+1
             print "proximity output   ", t1, time.ctime(time.time())
             connection = urllib2.urlopen("https://5fhwrhjoc3.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/production/productioncount?skey=76b89337-206c-4de3-a553-177dbf74e4ea&device_id=2&count="+str(t1))
if __name__ == '__main__':
              while 1:
                    p1 = Process(target=photo)
                    p1.start()
                    p2 = Process(target=proxi)
                    p2.start()
                    p1.join()
```

Comment: Since you're using python and transmitting data to AWS, you might consider using the [`boto3`](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) library which connects python directly to the AWS API and avoids needing to manage connections with `urllib2`. I've done psudo-continous data streaming using AWS Firehose service with `boto3`.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is library called "Threading".
Check the link here;
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_multithreading.htm

From this part you will define the functions as classes and initialize them with Thread library in an another class (like main). After that, in the main class you can define a mutual file (which can be tinyDB), in order to save the data inside the Pi 3 & safely deliver them to Cloud.
For tinyDB;
http://tinydb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting-started.html